# Lazy loading using module federation in angular without shell application?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I want to achieve the lazy loading using module federation without shell application using angular 16.

I configuring the module federation like this -

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({ 
   name: 'myapp',
   filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    exposes: {
       route1: './src/routes/route1.module.ts',
       route2: './src/routes/route2.module.ts'
    },
    remotes: {
       myApp: 'myApp'
    }
})
```

Defining the routes like this -

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
     path: 'route1',
     loadChildren: () => 
       loadRemoteModule({
           type: 'module',
           remoteEntry: "http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js", 
           exposedModule: "route1"
        }).then(m => m.Route1Module)
  },
  {
     path: 'route2',
     loadChildren: () => 
       loadRemoteModule({
           type: 'module',
           remoteEntry: "http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js", 
           exposedModule: "route2"
        }).then(m => m.Route2Module)
  }
]
```

This will create remoteEntry.js files as well but the lazy loading is not working. Getting below error when clicked on lazy route.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with lazy loading not working, you can try changing Route1Module to Route2Module in the second route definition.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: This was typo i have fixed it.

Comment: Did you try to check the network tab in your browser’s developer tools to ensure that the remoteEntry.js file is being loaded correctly and that the Route2Module is being loaded from the correct location?

Comment: remoteEntry.js is loaded in the browser, but giving error Attached the screenshot of error.